# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Tkinter' in python using python 3

Tags: python

I get the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Tkinter'` in Python 3. I am trying to run this piece of code.

```
from swampy.TurtleWorld import *
import Tkinter

world = TurtleWorld()
bob = Turtle()
fd(bob, 100)
lt(bob)
fd(bob, 100)
print (bob)
wait_for_user()
```

Comment: you must install that module with `pip install Tkinter`

Comment: you aren't actually using Tkinter in that code, just importing it. Does that even do anything?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like your code is using Tkinter at all, so you could just remove the line `import Tkinter`. In any case, you should be able to import Tkinter in Python always, because it is built into the standard library; the problem is that the module is named [`tkinter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html) in lowercase, not `Tkinter`, so it should be:

```
import tkinter
```

But again, if you are not going to use the module it would be clearer to remove that import statement.

Answer (score 1):

The way you are importing Tkinter uses the capitalization for Python 2.  In Python 3 Tkinter has a lower case 't'.  So for Python 3 you would write it as:

```
import tkinter
```

To make their programs work in both Python 2 and Python 3 I have seem many people write their code in the following manner:

```
try:
    import Tkinter
except:
    import tkinter
```

With the above you will have the correct import for whether you or not you are using Python 2 or Python 3.  I'd also recommend setting up as value for tkinter such as:

```
import tkinter as tk
```

This way while you are programming instead of writing `tkinter.Frame()` you can shorten it to `tk.Frame()`.  It makes it a lot quicker to code Tkinter programs.

I am assuming you are planning on implementing Tkinter later in your code as currently your code makes no use of it, so I hope this helps.  If you are not going to add anything using Tkinter, I would recommend removing the import.